# how to get element from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, dom

im trying to get a element from the url html file. element `<td>Thu Dec 18 10:33:19 EST 2014</td>` which is in the url html page that is passed into loadHTML function. which sends the html page string to another function called handler.  from the parser is it possible to get the specific .

```js
function loadHTML(spanId, url) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                handler(xmlhttp.responseText, spanId);
          }
};
xmlhttp.send();
}


function handler(responseText, spanId) {
var parser =new DOMParser();
parser.getDocument()
//get the date/time from parser 
var dateTime = …
//get class name from parser
var className = …

var span = document.getElementById(spanId);
span.innerHTML = dateTime;
span.className = className;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think you need to do it like this:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");

var dateTime = doc.querySelector("td.dateTime").innerHTML;
```

and set `class="dateTime"` on `<td>`

[From MDN on DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: or get a specific string from doc to dateTime

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can also set [`xhr.responseType = "document"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties) and directly get a document as result from the XHR.